# Quick Build problem with El Capitan

Tags: errors

[image]

Hi, I am new to Texmaker, and Latex generally. Can anybody please tell me how to solve this problem. It happens when I Quickbuild to see the pdf version. I am running Mac OS X El Capitan (perhaps this is important)

Thanks!